# How do I create a python real-time clock using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a python real-time clock using Tkinter. However, I do not know how to start.

Comment: Why is my question being downvoted? I would like to know why to improve my post. Please comment if you think this post can be improved.

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question into a different question is against policy when doing so invalidates one or more answers, even if the original question isn't what you really intended to ask. Your edit here invalidated an answer. Users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I've reverted your edit. You're *encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps linking this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Comment: @Makyen The comment conversation on [this Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382168/how-many-percent-of-questions-that-get-submitted-for-review-get-eventually-re-op) says they're banned from asking questions here.

Comment: @gparyani Then they would need to resolve that prior to asking a new question. The fact that they currently are in a question ban has no relevance with respect what level of change is permitted to a question. They still are not permitted to edit in a way which invalidates an answer.

Comment: @Makyen then Um, what should I do now with this question? I can't delete it, I can't add more details because that "invalidates the existing question," I can't ask another question, what do I do? Please help.

Comment: @Enderman Unfortunately, for this question, you're basically stuck. You asked an extremely broad/unclear question, but got an answer from someone who basically gave you exactly what you asked for, a complete implementation of a real-time clock in .`tkinter` (i.e. which would cover anywhere you might have been "stuck" on making a digital clock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I made my clock, assuming you want digital:

```python
# importing whole module 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

# importing strftime function to 
# retrieve system's time 
from time import strftime 

# creating tkinter window 
root = Tk() 
root.title('Clock') 

# This function is used to 
# display time on the label 
def time(): 
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p') 
    lbl.config(text = string) 
    lbl.after(1000, time) 

# Styling the label widget so that clock 
# will look more attractive 
lbl = Label(root, font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'), 
            background = 'purple', 
            foreground = 'white') 

# Placing clock at the centre 
# of the tkinter window 
lbl.pack(anchor = 'center') 
time() 

mainloop()
```

If you wanted an analog clock, you could do this:

```python
#list of imported modules
from tkinter import *
from math import cos, sin
from time import gmtime, sleep

#defining of secondary functions

def drawcircle(Alpha,Beta,Rayon,Couleur,can): #draw a circle base on center coord radius and color
    x1,y1,x2,y2=Alpha-Rayon, Beta-Rayon, Alpha+Rayon, Beta+Rayon
    can.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill=Couleur)

def drawPetAig(CoordA, CoordZ, Taille, Omega, can): #function to drawn the second hand of the clock
    Pi = 3.141592
    Omega = ((Omega/60)+1)*30
    can.create_line(CoordA + (Taille/3) * cos(Pi*(Omega/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/3) * sin(Pi*(Omega/180)), CoordA - (Taille/8) * cos(Pi*(Omega/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/8) * sin(Pi*(Omega/180)) )

def drawGrdAig(CoordA, CoordZ, Taille, Omega, can): #function to draw the minute hand, based on center coord and minutes.
    Pi = 3.141592
    Omega = (Omega-15)*6
    can.create_line(CoordA + (Taille/1.5) * cos(Pi*(Omega/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.5) * sin(Pi*(Omega/180)), CoordA - (Taille/6) * cos(Pi*(Omega/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/6) * sin(Pi*(Omega/180)))

def drawSecAig(CoordA, CoordZ, Taille, Omega, can): #function to draw the hour hand
    Pi = 3.141592
    Omega = (Omega-15) *6
    can.create_line(CoordA + (Taille/1.5) * cos(Pi*(Omega/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.5) * sin(Pi*(Omega/180)), CoordA - (Taille/6) * cos(Pi*(Omega/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/6) * sin(Pi*(Omega/180)), fill = "red")

def fondhorloge(CoordA, CoordZ, Taille, can1):  #function drawing the backgroud of the clock
    Pi = 3.141592
    drawcircle(CoordA, CoordZ, Taille + (Taille/10), "grey6",can1) #drawing the surrounding of the clock
    drawcircle(CoordA, CoordZ, Taille, "ivory3",can1)#backgroud
    drawcircle(CoordA, CoordZ, Taille/80, "grey6",can1)#central point/needle articulation
    can1.create_line(CoordA + (Taille - (Taille/15)), CoordZ, CoordA + (Taille - (Taille/5)), CoordZ) #drawing the N/S/E/W decorativ hour position
    can1.create_line(CoordA, CoordZ + (Taille - (Taille/15)), CoordA, CoordZ + (Taille - (Taille/5)))
    can1.create_line(CoordA - (Taille - (Taille/15)), CoordZ, CoordA - (Taille - (Taille/5)), CoordZ)
    can1.create_line(CoordA, CoordZ - (Taille - (Taille/15)), CoordA, CoordZ - (Taille - (Taille/5)))

    #here, this 4*2 line defined the position of the 8 intermediate line between the N/S/E/W decorativ line.
    can1.create_line(CoordA + (Taille/1.05) * cos(Pi*(30/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.05) * sin(Pi*(30/180)), CoordA + (Taille/1.20) * cos(Pi*(30/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.20) * sin(Pi*(30/180)))
    can1.create_line(CoordA + (Taille/1.05) * cos(Pi*(60/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.05) * sin(Pi*(60/180)), CoordA + (Taille/1.20) * cos(Pi*(60/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.20) * sin(Pi*(60/180)))

    can1.create_line(CoordA - (Taille/1.05) * cos(Pi*(30/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/1.05) * sin(Pi*(30/180)), CoordA - (Taille/1.20) * cos(Pi*(30/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/1.20) * sin(Pi*(30/180)))
    can1.create_line(CoordA - (Taille/1.05) * cos(Pi*(60/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/1.05) * sin(Pi*(60/180)), CoordA - (Taille/1.20) * cos(Pi*(60/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/1.20) * sin(Pi*(60/180)))

    can1.create_line(CoordA + (Taille/1.05) * cos(Pi*(30/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/1.05) * sin(Pi*(30/180)), CoordA + (Taille/1.20) * cos(Pi*(30/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/1.20) * sin(Pi*(30/180)))
    can1.create_line(CoordA + (Taille/1.05) * cos(Pi*(60/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/1.05) * sin(Pi*(60/180)), CoordA + (Taille/1.20) * cos(Pi*(60/180)), CoordZ - (Taille/1.20) * sin(Pi*(60/180)))

    can1.create_line(CoordA - (Taille/1.05) * cos(Pi*(30/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.05) * sin(Pi*(30/180)), CoordA - (Taille/1.20) * cos(Pi*(30/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.20) * sin(Pi*(30/180)))
    can1.create_line(CoordA - (Taille/1.05) * cos(Pi*(60/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.05) * sin(Pi*(60/180)), CoordA - (Taille/1.20) * cos(Pi*(60/180)), CoordZ + (Taille/1.20) * sin(Pi*(60/180)))

#PRINCIPLE FUNCTION (here the problem starts)

def HORLOGE1(Gamma, Pi, Epsylon):# draw a clock with the center position x/x = gamma/pi and the radius = epsylon

    fondhorloge(Gamma, Pi, Epsylon, can1)# extracting time value
    patate = gmtime()
    heure = patate[3] + 1  # "+1" is changing time from english time to french time :P
    minute = patate[4]
    seconde = patate[5]

    print(heure, minute, seconde) # a simple test to watch what the programm is doing (run it, and you'll see, that this test is done tausend time per second, that why I think the problem is here.)
    drawPetAig(Gamma, Pi, Epsylon, minute, can1)
    drawGrdAig(Gamma, Pi, Epsylon, minute, can1)
    drawSecAig(Gamma, Pi, Epsylon, seconde, can1)
    fen1.after(1000, lambda: HORLOGE1(250, 250, 200))

#execution of the main function

fen1 = Tk()
can1 = Canvas(fen1, bg="white", height=500, width=500)
can1.pack()

HORLOGE1(250, 250, 200)

fen1.mainloop()
fen1.destroy()
```

Comment: How would you change the time zone of these clocks? My time zone is Pacific Standard Time in the US.